# Can layout be a root component in Vaadin Window?

Tags: java, vaadin

I am just exploring Vaadin 7 and I'm a bit frustrated to face a wall right at the start. Experienced in Swing I was happy to find Vaadin layouts are so simple and they are just like other components (they actually are Components, according to the class hierarchy). However, I faced a problem building my first Window.
So let's say I have a CustomComponent of such composition:

```
VerticalLayout
|
--TextArea
|
--Button
```

Which in the code will look like this:

```
public class SOComplicatedComponent extends CustomComponent {

    private VerticalLayout mainLayout;
    private TextArea textArea;
    private Button button;

    public SOComplicatedComponent() {
        buildMainLayout();
        setCompositionRoot(mainLayout);
    }

    private VerticalLayout buildMainLayout() {
        // common part: create layout
        mainLayout = new VerticalLayout();
        mainLayout.setWidth("100%");
        mainLayout.setHeight("100%");

        // top-level component properties
        setWidth("100.0%");
        setHeight("100.0%");

        // textArea
        textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setValue("hey, this button is supposed to be under me!");
        textArea.setSizeUndefined();
        mainLayout.addComponent(textArea);

        //button
        button = new Button("Ooops");
        button.setSizeUndefined();
        mainLayout.addComponent(button);

        return mainLayout;
    }

}
```

Then I'm constructing a Window in a following way:

```
public class MyUI extends UI{

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        ...
        Window window = new Window("Help me SO", new SOComplicatedComponent());
        addWindow();
    }
}
```

As a result I get a window with the TextArea and Button overlapping. When I resize the Window, contents stretch and the Layout becaomes OK, however I thought the Window is supposed to automatically fit to the contents size, isn't it?

OK, time for a final

**QUESTION**

I want the Button to be under the TextArea in my Window and make the Window size automatically fit its contents. What is the most proper way of achieving that in Vaadin 7?

Thanks

Comment: Clarified the question after answer by @Charles Anthony - it's actually not about the Layout is completely ignored, but the Window does not fit its contents automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular instance, there is no need for a separate Window - in Vaadin 7, Windows are actually child windows of the main UI; according to your comments, you do want a floating window. That's cool - but but a UI really should have some content, even if it's empty (otherwise rendering looks a little odd).
So, 
You should simply be able to do

```
public class MyUI extends UI {

  @Override
  protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    // You need to have some content on the UI, even if it's empty - otherwise it looks odd
    // Here, I'm just adding an empty layout
    VerticalLayout content = new VerticalLayout();
    content.setSizeFull();
    setContent(content);

    // Adding a child window, and centering it for kicks
    Window window = new Window("Help me SO", new SOComplicatedComponent());
    window.center();
    addWindow(window);

  }
}
```

The [AbsoluteLayout](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/layout.absolutelayout.html]AbsoluteLayout) requires that you specify the location of your components. For a simple Vertical layout (i.e. TextField above Button) you would typically use the [VerticalLayout](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/layout.orderedlayout.html)

Also, setSizeFull means "make this component take all of the space allowed by it's container" - 
which gets a bit confusing when you want the parent to make the child component as big as it needs to be, and no bigger. I think you really want to use "setSizeUndefined" for the CustomComponent too. So, putting all that together should give you this:

```
public class SOComplicatedComponent extends CustomComponent {

  private VerticalLayout mainLayout;
  private TextArea textArea;
  private Button button;

  public SOComplicatedComponent() {
    buildMainLayout();
    setCompositionRoot(mainLayout);
  }

  private VerticalLayout buildMainLayout() {
    // common part: create layout
    mainLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    mainLayout.setSpacing(true);
    mainLayout.setMargin(true);

    // top-level component properties
    /* CSA : SizeUndefined means "take as much space as my content needs" */
    setSizeUndefined();

    // textArea
    textArea = new TextArea();
    textArea.setValue("hey, this button is supposed to be under me!");
    textArea.setSizeUndefined();
    mainLayout.addComponent(textArea);

    //button
    button = new Button("Ooops");
    button.setSizeUndefined();
    mainLayout.addComponent(button);

    return mainLayout;
  }

}
```

For me, that renders like this :
[image: Example Image]

Comment: OK, that was my stupid mistake with that AbsoluteLayout, I fixed my code example already. I'm using VerticalLayout and it's a little bit better than with AbsoluteLayout which obviously will not work this way that easy. However, the the Button is still overlapping the TextArea. Actually the when I resize the Window manually, the layout is stretched and it becomes OK, but I thought the Window is supposed to automatically resize to fit the Contents...

Comment: And one more thing - I actually need a sub-window, a kind of floating one, so I think this cannot be achieved by just placing the CustomComponent directly to UI?

Comment: Re: Floating Window - ok, yes, you need to do `addWindow(window)

Comment: Re: Layout. Actually, in this case, I don't think you want setSizeFull() but setSizeUndefined() (for both the layout AND the custom component). You might want to do a mainLayout.setSpacing(true) and mainLayout.setMarging(true) for a bit of spacing too.

Basically, I assume you want the window to take just as much space as it needs => setSizeUndefined()

Comment: I've updated my answer with my suggested code, along with a screenshot of the result...

Comment: Yep, this helps, thanks a lot! My original Window was much more complex and I think I've tried playing with this setSizeUndefined, but the setWidth/Height("100%") probably overrided this setting.